# Concatenar variável com outra variável PHP

Tags: php

Meus `inputs` estão sendo gerados a partir de uma repetição do Javascript nomeando-os da seguinte forma: `` input.setAttribute("name",`tubo_${i}`) `` e `` input.setAttribute("name",`largura_${i}`) ``

Meu problema é quando preciso tratar e separar esses valores no PHP, recebo os itens via `$_POST`.

`print_r($_POST)`:

```php
Array
(
    [tubo_0] => tubo1
    [largura_0] => largura1
    [tubo_1] => tubo2
    [largura_1] => largura2
)
```

Preciso criar um `array` contendo os valores dos **tubos** e outro `array` com o valor das **larguras**.
Segue a minha tentativa falha:

```php
extract($_POST);
$qtdModelos = (count($_POST)) / 2;

for ($i=0; $i < $qtdModelos ; $i++) { 
    $arrayTubo[] = $tubo_.$i;
    $arrayLargura[] = $largura_.$i;
}

print_r($arrayTubo);
print_r($arrayLargura);
```

**Resultado**

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
```

Somente os valores de `$i` estão sendo armazenados, ou seja, as variáveis não estão sendo "concatenadas" da maneira que eu gostaria.

Comment: O certo não seria você fazer por exemplo: for ($i=0; $i < $qtdModelos ; $i++) { 
    $arrayTubo[] = $tubo_[$i];
    $arrayLargura[] = $largura_[$i];
}

???

Comment: São variáveis gerada a partir do extract($_POST), neste exemplo, as variáveis existentes são $tubo_0, $tubo_1, $largura_0 e $largura_1.
Preciso armazená-las dentro de arrays específicos para cada propriedade.

Comment: Por que não faz ``input.setAttribute("name",`tubo[${i}]['tubo']`)`` e  ``input.setAttribute("name",`tubo[${i}]['largura']`)``? Assim já terá um *array* com os dados organizados.

Comment: A resposta do Rafael S. resolveu meu problema, desta maneira `${tubo_.$i}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não me engano você pode fazer isso:

```
${'tubo_' . $i}
```

Deixando seu código dessa forma:

```
extract($_POST);
$qtdModelos = (count($_POST)) / 2;

for ($i=0; $i < $qtdModelos ; $i++) { 
    $arrayTubo[] = ${tubo_.$i};
    $arrayLargura[] = ${largura_.$i};
}

print_r($arrayTubo);
print_r($arrayLargura);
```

Nesse [link](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php) fala um pouco sobre isso.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de concatenar no nome, use o valor de `i` como índice:

```html
Tubo 1
Nome: <input type="text" name="tubo[0]">
Largura: <input type="text" name="largura[0]">

Tubo 2
Nome: <input type="text" name="tubo[1]">
Largura: <input type="text" name="largura[1]">
```

Assim, quando enviar para o PHP, poderá recuperar os diferentes *arrays* com `$_POST['tubo']` e `$_POST['largura']`.

Para tal, ao invés de fazer:

```
input.setAttribute("name",`tubo_${i}`)
```

Você poderia fazer:

```
input.setAttribute("name",`tubo[${i}]`)
```

---

Se os dois campos são relacionados entre si, você consegue agrupar melhor seus dados no HTML. Ao invés de concatenar o valor de `i` no nome do campo, use-o como índice do *array* e defina as colunas nesse índice.

```html
Tubo 1
Nome: <input type="text" name="tubo[0][nome]">
Largura: <input type="text" name="tubo[0][largura]">

Tubo 2
Nome: <input type="text" name="tubo[1][nome]">
Largura: <input type="text" name="tubo[1][largura]">
```

Assim, quando enviar ao PHP, o valor de `$_POST` será algo como:

```
Array
(
    [tubo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ['nome'] => tubo1
                    ['largura'] => 100
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    ['nome'] => tubo2
                    ['largura'] => 200
                )

        )

)
```

Assim, para tratar os valores, bastaria percorrer esse *array* e consumir as informações. Uma forma seria:

```php
foreach ($_POST['tubo'] as $tubo) {
    echo "O tubo {$tubo['nome']} possui largura {$tubo['largura']}";
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://AquaOverduePrinter.acwoss.repl.co)</sup>

Comment: Realmente os dados ficam muito mais organizador, mas o meu objetivo não é juntar **tubo** com **largura**, e sim separar essas propriedades em diferentes arrays no PHP, para eu poder tratá-los e inseri-los no banco de dados em diferentes colunas.

Comment: @GabrielZedine Para isso bastaria fazer `array_column($_POST['tubo'], "largura")`, ou nomear de acordo os campos, por exemplo `name="largura[0]"` e buscar direto o valor de `$_POST['largura']`